# My .NET (dotnet) developer pack install doesn't seem to work

Tags: .net-framework, windows-installer

I'm trying to install .NET developer pack 4.7.2. I've downloaded the installer from the [MS dotnet download website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net472). I run the installer and it says it succeeded. If I run it again it says .NET 4.7.2 Developer Pack is already installed and I can repair or uninstall. But if I look around I cannot find any clue that .NET 4.7.2 developer pack (AKA .NET 4.7.2 SDK) is installed. (Only some other versions are installed.)

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 22H2 has .NET 4.8.1 built-in 4.7.2 and 4.8.1 cannot be installed on the same system. I assume you want the developer pack so you use the .NET 4.7.2 Targeting Pack within Visual Studio? It appears you have a very old version of .NET Core installed (more than 4 years old). The command you’re using is only picking up .NET Core installations by the way.

Comment: As per these instructions perhaps specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=msvc-170#to-change-the-platform-toolset

Comment: Just to clarify, before more confusion arises: The _targeting pack_ is not the framework and can be installed and _must_ be used when _targeting_ 4.7.2.